# History of methods and functions that were called during last postback

Tags: asp.net

Is there a built in way to get a full history what has been done during the last postback, what methods and functions that were called? Something like the stack trace when there is an error, but in this case, there is no error on the server.

**Update**

I need to be able to save the history to a database. Sometimes my users get a problem with ajax.net and I want to see what happen to cause the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jamie Dixon said, you can use the StackTrace object to get a full stack trace at any time. It's an instantiable class. However, note that it will not include the parameter values, and the names of generic methods will be somewhat...mangled. Further, if the call came from Visual Basic, parameter names may look a bit odd.

More importantly, a full stack trace for every method call is more than likely overkill for your needs. It's expensive to create. And once you have it, where will you store it? You'll have to put it somewhere. Now you're looking at some sort of storage medium.

Go with a logging/tracing tool. Preferably something you don't have to build and maintain yourself. What you'd like to be able to do, however, is only enable logging/tracing on an as-needed basis, to capture information when you need it. It can hamper performance.

Answer (score 0):

The StackTrace should be available to you regardless of whether there's an error or not.

Whilst debugging look in: Debug/Windows/Call Stack

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically but you can use tracing or a logging tool like log4net.

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2012/01/22/log4net-log-to-a-javascript-console.aspx